# How to Establish Transparency That Subtracts From Lower Layers - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, layers, transparency, digital

For reference, I am using the livepaint tool to make a design, and I want to subtract an area from that livepaint using *another* livepaint. This is all fine and dandy, I just merge the livepaints or layer one atop the other. However, the lower livepaint system has thickness to the lines which shows through if I try to make the color value null in the desired area. How would I establish one livepaint as dominant in all values to anything below it?

Or should I convert everything to a shape and then do a subtract? I don't really want to resort to this option because it would rasterize what I want to be a vector image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out! I just had to use a transparency mask.

Comment: Hi Sunsprint. Good for you! We love it when users can self-answer their question. You can even 'accept' your own answer so the system can mark it solved. One thing though: would you mind adding some explanation as to how you solved your question? Maybe a screenshot or a step-by-step guide. Just so future visitors can replicate your solution and be as happy as you are. :) 
Thanks for your contributions. Feel free to look around the site, ask more questions or answer other questions.

Comment: I would consider using knockout groups as a more flexible alternative. Also i highly recommend you don't use live paint buckets but shape building instead